# Inserting form records into database

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I've a problem here. I am fetching a form details in my code. Now I have to insert that details in to database. In the below query , how can I make it possible.(without using prepared statement).

```
String user=req.getParameter("un");
String pass=req.getParameter("pass");
//error is here
String sql="insert into test.users(username,password) values(+user, +pass)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try this

```
String sql=
"Insert into test.users(username,password) values(' "+user+" ',' "+pass+" ' )";
```

I strongly suggest to use Prepared Statement.